# How to show the location of the code that invokes `System.out.print` when printing by configuring Eclipse console in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, file-location

How to show the location of the code that invokes `System.out.print` when printing by configuring Eclipse console in java?

When I use `console.log` in Javascript in Vscode / Chrome, it always shows the location of the code that invokes `console.log`. 
I can click on that & jump right into that location.

But Java in Eclipse seems never has such feature? Why? (there is no post online about this too?)

Comment: But of course you should use the debug tool for debugging instead of just typing `sout` everywhere. And programming/software development is offtopic here.

Comment: @Gantendo I read through those before, but those are not as good as built-in solutions that Javascript ide can provide. So I wonder why Java ide does not provide such feature. \ (As for debug, sometimes print is just faster)

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/0u4pbcpvprja1-jpg.322786/

Comment: When you run a Java program from Eclipse a separate JVM is started. Eclipse just receives the output from the JVM and has no way to find out exactly where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loggers correctly configured to get path of file but if you want to debug with `System.out.Print` it is not a good way of doing.
Prefer run the debugger, you can have more and better information.
The beginner solution can be to add specific text to each like `"Test1"` then `"Test2"`
Java is not supposed to log something when you ask it to print something. JS `console.log` is a logger not a printer like explained in the name.